# Using Vue.set in object with multiple nested objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I am trying to use `Vue.set()` to update a state object in Vue 2.

This is what the object looks like:

```
state: {
    entries: [
        // entry 1
        fields: {
            someProperties : ''
            // here I would like to add another property named 'googleInfos'
        }
    ], [
        // entry 2
        fields: {
            someProperties : ''
            // here I would like to add another property named 'googleInfos'

        }
    ]
}
```

So far, I was updating it with this mutation. I'm mutating each entry separately because they have different content.

```
ADD_GOOGLE_INFOS (state, {index, infos}) {
    state.entries[index].fields.googleInfos = infos
}
```

Now, I'm trying to implement `Vue.set()` to avoid a [change detection caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

My problem is that I can't find the proper way to add it.

Here's how Vue.set() is supposed to work :

```
Vue.set(state.object, key, value)
```

So I tried this, which doesn't seem to work because `state.entries[index]` is not an object of first rank :

```
Vue.set(state.entries[index], 'fields.googleInfos', infos)
```

But this doesn't work either :

```
Vue.set(state.entries, '[index].fields.googleInfos', infos)
```

Any one has a clue what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Please try this in your mutation : `Vue.set(state.entries[index].fields, 'googleInfos', infos)`

Comment: It works ! I don't know why I thought it needed to be only the name of the property and not it's children. Do you want to put that as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: Your state object got me confused, Are you using vuex?

Comment: Done, glad to help !

Comment: @PatrickCyiza Yes I am using Vuex, why?

Comment: Are you using vuex? @Marine Le Borgne

Comment: @anhlee yes, why?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The only non-reactive part is the new property you try to add in the `fields` object.

In order to add the `googleInfos` property, you have to set it in the mutation like this :

```
ADD_GOOGLE_INFOS (state, {index, infos}) {
    Vue.set(state.entries[index].fields, 'googleInfos', infos);
}
```

Comment: Be sure that Vue is imported, otherwise you may not even get an error

Comment: @Uygar, its safer to use `this.$set` instead of `Vue.set` and avoid the issue altogether.